# Ternary operator usage error, "ERROR:void value not ignored as it ought to be"

Tags: c, logical-and

```
(choice=='Y'||choice=='y')?((printf("\n...The program is now resetting...\n")&&(main()))):((printf("\n\tThank you for trying out the BPCC App.\n"))&&(exit(0)));
```

If I remove the `exit(0)` the whole program runs correctly but I need to include the `exit(0)`.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Don't call main recursively. Use loops. And if you want a "reset", don't forget to release all resources you have allocated (free memory, close files etc.)

Comment: Write one thing in one line. Your code, in its current form, is hard to read

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `C11` standard, chapter 6.5.13, Logical AND [`&&`] operator

> Each of the operands shall have scalar type.

and from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit) of `exit()`

> `void exit(int status);`

now, the `void` is not a valid value (or scalar type). So, you cannot write

```
...:((printf("\n\tThank you for trying out the BPCC App.\n"))&&(exit(0)));
                                                               |--------|
                                        The return value of `exit()` is used
                                            as one of the operands of `&&` here
```

Hence the error. You cannot write a logic using the *return value* of `exit()` (what's the point, basically?). You have to think of something alternative. (like calling `exit()` as the very next instruction or similar). One possible approach, as metioned in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30298902/2173917) by Mr. **@BLUEPIXY**, is to make use of `comma` operator [`,`], as below

```
.... (printf("\n\tThank you for trying out the BPCC App.\n")) , (exit(0))
```

That said, the approach (calling `main()` recursively) is not considered a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
(printf("message") && (exit(0),1))
```

or

```
(printf("message") , exit(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `exit` is declared the following way

```
_Noreturn void exit(int status);
```

So you may not use it in expressions like this

```
(printf("\n\tThank you for trying out the BPCC App.\n"))&&(exit(0))
```

Instead of operator && you can use the comma operator.

Thus the ternary operator can look the following way

```
( choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y' ) 
   ? ( printf( "\n...The program is now resetting...\n" ) , ( void )main() )
   : ( printf( "\n\tThank you for trying out the BPCC App.\n" ), exit( 0 ) );
```

Or the following way

```
( choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y' ) 
   ? ( printf( "\n...The program is now resetting...\n" ) , exit( main() ) )
   : ( printf( "\n\tThank you for trying out the BPCC App.\n" ), exit( 0 ) );
```